# IE11 no download prompt, always tries to open

Tags: javascript

I have a function to download text file from server. It works on chrome but not work with IE 11.
Please help me. 
Thanks and Regards.

```
        // Get file name from url.
        var filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1).split("?")[0];
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', url, true);
        xhr.responseType = 'blob ';

        xhr.onload = function () {
            var a = document.createElement('a');
            a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(xhr.response); // xhr.response is a blob
            a.download = filename; // Set the file name.
            a.style.display = 'none';
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.click();
        };

        xhr.send();
        xhr.onerror = function (e) {
            alert("Error " + e.target.status + " occurred while receiving the document.");
        };
```

Comment: what kind of file is it? pdf,txt ....?

Comment: either the filename extension, or the mime-type is causing this - forcing a mimetype of `application/octet-stream` should fix your issue

Comment: it's .txt file. text plain